# Compare two arrays and after regex return unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, underscore.js

I have two arrays. One with a list of emails and another with a list of strings that when matched, should be rejected.

```
array1 = [ 'appstore@myntra.com',
  'life@updates.cricinfo.com',
  'pqr@gmail.com',
  'noreply-de9ae870@plus.google.com',
  'updates-24997849@shtyle.fm',
  'whatsup@gmail.com',
  'some@relatas.com',
  'smqwe@gmail.com' ]

array 2 = [ /calendar-notification/i,
  /feedproxy/i,
  /techgig/i,
  /team/i,
  /blog/i,
  /info/i,
  /support/i,
  /admin/i,
  /hello/i,
  /no-reply/i,
  /noreply/i,
  /reply/i,
  /help/i,
  /mailer-daemon/i,
  /googlemail.com/i,
  /mail-noreply/i,
  /alert/i,
  /calendar-notification/i,
  /eBay/i,
  /flipkartletters/i,
  /pinterest/i,
  /dobambam.com/i,
  /notify/i,
  /offers/i,
  /iicicibank/i,
  /indiatimes/i,
  /info@relatas.in/i,
  /facebookmail/i,
  /message/i,
  /facebookmail.com/i,
  /notification/i,
  /youcanreply/i,
  /jobs/i,
  /news/i,
  /linkedin/i,
  /list/i ]
```

array2 contains all the invalid emails that I want to reject.

How do I compare these two arrays and remove the invalid emails from array1 such that I get

```
array3 = [ 'appstore@myntra.com',
  'life@updates.cricinfo.com',
  'pqr@gmail.com',
  'whatsup@gmail.com',
  'some@relatas.com',
  'smqwe@gmail.com' ]
```

Comment: I don't see anyother way apart from looping through each value of arr1 and if a match with arr2 occurs then splice that value from the arr1. would this work for you? Or are you looking for an optimized solution?

Comment: This would work, but an optimized solution is always preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically `filter` them:

```
var newArray = array1.filter(function (elem) {
    var ok = true
    array2.forEach(function (tester) {
        if (tester.test(elem)) {
            ok = false;
        }
    });
    return ok
});
```

**update**

As @torazaburo suggested, using `some` we can have a much cleaner solution:

```
var newArray = array1.filter(function (elem) {
    return !array2.some(function (tester) {
        return tester.test(elem)
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried Thomas's edit. It doesn't work. Adam's original did work.

Comment: Use `some` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @torazaburo, `some` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged the question with underscore, so i think you use underscore... Then use a temp array and iterate clever:

```
var array_temp = [];

while(array1.length > 0) {
  var mail = array1.shift();
  _.each(array2, function(expression) {
    if(mail.match(expression)) {
      array3.push(mail);
    } else {
      array_temp.push(mail);
    }
  });
}

array1 = array_temp; array_temp = null;
```

Comment: sorry - i have overseen, that array3 should hold the remaining mails - my method shows how to split in two arrays - one with valid and one with invalid adresses, but i think you see the magic and could use it how you need